# google.protobuf.json_format.MessageToJson changes names of fields. How to avoid it?

Tags: json, protocol-buffers

I have some protocol buffer message object. So I want to serialize it in such way:

```
import json
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson

with open("file.json", 'w') as fjs:
    fjs.write(MessageToJson(message_object))
```

But it change the names of object fields.
For example I had such object:

```
[{
    "id": "333333",
    "creation_timestamp": 2011,
}]
```

[MessageToJson](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/) changed it fields to:

```
[{
  "id": "333333",
  "creationTimestamp": "2011",
}]
```

i.e `creation_timestamp` is changed to `creationTimestamp` and `2011` is done to `"2011"`. How to avoid it?

Comment: If you read it back with the google protobuf Parse function, does it read the timestamp correctly?

Comment: I don't know about the camelCasing but the `2011` -> `"2011"` change is probably because the value is a 64-bit integer, which is impossible to represent accurately as a JSON number, hence the convention is to stringify it.

Answer (score 9):

I read the source code for this, and turns out that you can pass an option `preserving_proto_field_name=True` to `MessageToJson`.