# Make gRPC messages JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, grpc, grpc-python, grpc-node

I have a gRPC definition that contains repeated scalar values.

For example

```proto
message Request {
  bool dryrun = 1;   
  bool verbose = 2;
  bool enabled = 3;
  float ratio = 4;
  int32 count = 5;
  string somevar = 6;
  bool withcondition = 7;
  bool nocondition = 8;
  float portion = 9;
  int32 population = 10;
  string xvars = 11;
  string singleoption = 12;
  repeated int32 multioptions = 13;
}
```

I noticed that when this request gets sent to a Python server, `mylist` is converted to a `RepeatedScalarContainer`, which is not JSON serializable. [Some SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860448/object-of-type-repeatedcompositecontainer-is-not-json-serializable) suggest that I use

```py
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
serialized = MessageToJson(original)
```

to convert a protobuf message to a valid JSON object.
But in my case, doing the above on the received Python object gives me a truncated one

```json
{
  "enabled": true,
  "ratio": 0.5,
  "count": 100,
  "somevar": "/input",
  "withcondition": true,
  "singleoption": "option1",
  "multioptions": [
    1,
    3
  ]
}
```

You can see that a bunch of message attributes are missing.

As a workaround, I could still extract the attributes of the received object to recover the data and convert them to JSON serializable by brute-force, but this seems ugly and flaky. Here is my way

```py
    def handle_request(request):
        all_attrs = dir(request)
        i_last_private_attr = next((a for a, attr in enumerate(reversed(all_attrs)) if attr.startswith('_')), None)
        if not i_last_private_attr:
            _logger.error('Failed to find any request')
            return
        i_first_arg_attr = len(all_attrs) - i_last_private_attr
        req_dict = {attr: getattr(request, attr) for attr in all_attrs[i_first_arg_attr:]}
        for k, v in req_dict.items():
            if isinstance(v, Iterable) and not isinstance(v, (dict, list, tuple, str)):
                req_dict[k] = list(req_dict[k])
```

How should I make the received raw gRPC request work like a Python object containing only builtin primitive value types?

Comment: for efficiency grpc normally doesn't transmit fields which contain their default values.  That's why they disappear.  The receiver will restore those fields in the receive message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself.

There is an option `including_default_value_fields` with `json_format.MessageToJson()`. When set to `False`, all default fields are not printed to JSON, although they are physically sent through the wire.

Unfortunately, the option was turned off by default.

After setting it to `True`, the problem is gone.